# Sort desc if item is included in an array with lodash or with out

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a array of objects like so:

```
const attendList = [
{
  "first": "John",
  "last": "Foo",
  "uid": "-Lz8YxIYM_4L3f9nKM70",
},
{
  "first": "Jake",
  "last": "Foo",
  "uid": "-Lz8YxIYM_4L3fsdfM70",
}
...
]
```

Then I have an array containing the keys

```
const found = ["-Lz8YxIYM_4L3fsdfM70", "-Lz8YxIYM_4L3fsdf333", "-Lz8YxIYM_r4hfsdf333" ]
```

I want to sort attendList by placing the items that are in found at the bottom of the list.  My incorrect attempt (using lodash) is:

```
let SetItemsLast = _.sortBy(attendList, ({uid}) => found.includes(uid) ? 0:1);
```

I'm obviously not doing it correctly.  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you need to keep the attendList items in order otherwise.

```
  let SetItemsLast = attendList.sort((a, b)=>{
    if(found.includes(a.uid)){
      return 1;
    }
    if(found.includes(b.uid)){
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

If you don't care whether the items at the bottom remain in order, you can just do this.

```
  let SetItemsLast = attendList.sort((a, b)=>{ return found.includes(b.uid) ? -1:0; });
```